# python: extracting variables from string templates

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am familiar with the ability to insert variables into a string using [Templates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings), like this:

```
Template('value is between $min and $max').substitute(min=5, max=10)
```

What I now want to know is if it is possible to do the reverse.  I want to take a string, and extract the values from it using a template, so that I have some data structure (preferably just named variables, but a dict is fine) that contains the extracted values.  For example:

```
>>> string = 'value is between 5 and 10'
>>> d = Backwards_template('value is between $min and $max').extract(string)
>>> print d
{'min': '5', 'max':'10'}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's called [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
string = 'value is between 5 and 10'
m = re.match(r'value is between (.*) and (.*)', string)
print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Output:

```
5 10
```

---

*Update 1.* Names can be given to groups:

```
m = re.match(r'value is between (?P<min>.*) and (?P<max>.*)', string)
print(m.group('min'), m.group('max'))
```

But this feature is not used often, as there are usually enough problems with a more important aspect: how to capture exactly what you want (with this particular case that's not a big deal, but even here: what if the string is `value is between 1 and 2 and 3` -- should the string be accepted and what's the `min` and `max`?).

---

*Update 2.* Rather than making a precise regex, it's sometimes easier to combine regular expressions and "regular" code like this:

```
m = re.match(r'value is between (?P<min>.*) and (?P<max>.*)', string)
try:
    value_min = float(m.group('min'))
    value_max = float(m.group('max'))
except (AttributeError, ValueError):  # no match or failed conversion
    value_min = None
    value_max = None
```

This combined approach is especially worth remembering when your text consists of many chunks (like phrases in quotes of different types) to be processed: in tricky cases, it's harder to define a single regex to handle both delimiters and contents of chunks than to define several steps like `text.split()`, optional merging of chunks, and independent processing of each chunk (using regexes and other means).

Comment: perfect! only question, is it possible to name the arguments in a cleaner way, rather than just using `m.group([position])`?

Comment: What if we use this: `m = re.match(r'value is between (?P<min>\d+) and (?P<max>\d+)', string)`?  This should only match a string of consecutive digits, correct?  so the string "value is between 1 and 2 and 3" would not match (preferably returning something useful, such as `None` or raising an error

Comment: I just tried that, and it returns with `'min'` being '5' and `'max'` being `'7'`.  Is there a way to tell it to fail if the string does not match the regex exactly?

Comment: @ewok Regarding the digits: that's right, but what about numbers like `-1`, `-1.23`, `-1.23e4` (i.e. -1.23 * 10^4). Is `.1` a valid number? `1.`? `.`? Regarding the match, it will actually match, the `and 3` will be ignored. That's a big topic, and one of the best books on regular expressions is this: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do.

Comment: @ewok About the exactness: yes, you can add `$` (`expect the end-of-line`): `r'value is between (.*) and (.*)$'`.

Comment: I'm probably trying to solve a problem that has been solved a million times now, but how about `r'value is between (?P<min>-?\d+\.?\d*) and (?P<max>-?\d+\.?\d*)$'`?  That should pass for positive and negative numbers, as well as decimals and non-decimals (though it forces you to use `0.1` rather than simply `.1`). I'm fine not supporting `e` notation.

Comment: @ewok Seems OK for what you described (although `-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?` would be slightly more logical). I've updated the answer mentioning another approach.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to perfectly reverse the substitution. The problem is that some strings are ambiguous, for example

```
value is between 5 and 7 and 10
```

would have two possible solutions: `min = "5", max = "7 and 10"` and `min = "5 and 7", max = "10"`

However, you might be able to achieve useful results with regex:

```
import re

string = 'value is between 5 and 10'
template= 'value is between $min and $max'

pattern= re.escape(template)
pattern= re.sub(r'\\\$(\w+)', r'(?P<\1>.*)', pattern)
match= re.match(pattern, string)
print(match.groupdict()) # output: {'max': '10', 'min': '5'}
```

Comment: this looks like it would work. can you resolve the ambiguity by somehow structuring the template? what i mean is can you pass in a regex to the template that basically says "`$min` is the smallest string that matches the regex `\d+`". That would make is so if you got "value is between 5 and 7 and 10", you would simply get an error (which would be helpful)

Comment: @ewok, Yes, if you have additional information about the variables, like "min is a number", then you can reduce the ambiguity by using an appropriate regex. But there will always be some templates and strings that will be ambiguous. `$number1$number2` for example, or similar. It all depends on the format of your templates. If you're lucky you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The [`behave` module](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/install.html#using-the-github-repository) for Behavior-Driven Development provides a few different mechanisms for specifying and [parsing templates.](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#step-parameters)

Depending on the complexity of your templates, and the other needs of your app, you might find one or the other most useful. (Plus, you can steal their pre-written code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difflib module to compare the two strings and pull out the information you want.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html

For example:

```
import difflib

def backwards_template(my_string, template):
    my_lib = {}
    entry = ''
    value = ''

    for s in difflib.ndiff(my_string, template):
        if s[0]==' ':
            if entry != '' and value != '':
                my_lib[entry] = value 
                entry = ''
                value = ''   
        elif s[0]=='-':
            value += s[2]
        elif s[0]=='+':
            if s[2] != '$':
                entry += s[2]

    # check ending if non-empty
    if entry != '' and value != '':
        my_lib[entry] = value

    return my_lib

my_string = 'value is between 5 and 10'
template = 'value is between $min and $max'     

print(backwards_template(my_string, template))
```

Gives: 
{'min': '5', 'max': '10'}